# I feel robust is overused

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I feel robust is used too often and incorrectly when describing processes and systems.  What would be other possible words to describe processes and systems besides: effective, efficacious, and sound?

Comment: Usually questions which can be resolved by the use of a generally available reference -- in this case, a thesaurus -- are closed, because askers are as capable of using those resources as answerers are. That said, the connotations of *robust* in the context you mention are less about efficacy and effective was than they are about the soundness. So I would focus on that branch of synonyms; hale, hearty, sturdy, stout, etc.

Comment: I think it's unclear what you actually want to express. You say that *robust* is misused and then mention words with different meanings. Are you seeking a synonym for robust, one of the other words, or something else altogether? The actual question, "What would be other possible words to describe processes and systems besides: effective, efficacious, and sound?", leaves a huge number of possibilities, both positive and negative.

Comment: My poiny was that robust is used very often these days (particularly in the business world) to describe processes and systems and it is not clear what they are trying to convey.  What is your opinion on the word?  I think that it the word is thrown into sentences when it is not required.

Comment: Here is a good example that illustrates my point:          http://www.ebizq.net/blogs/ebizq_forum/2012/07/what-makes-a-business-process-robust.php

Comment: @BenDaniels My opinion is that if someone says that a process or system is robust that implies some degree of resilience.

Comment: @BenDaniels I think that the linked discussion fits with the meaning I expect. (They appear to discuss how to achieve robustness rather than what it means, even though some of them state otherwise.)

Comment: In my opinion, while the word may or may not be overused, the concept does not occur nearly often enough.

Comment: I'm a **fault tolerant** system, myself. **Homeostasis** *will be* maintained!

Comment: I think of robust as a synonym for "godlike." ^_^

Comment: There are indeed several different but related conditions when it comes to handling failures/errors well: fault-tolerant, fault-resistant, fail-safe and redundancy/fail-over. However, there is only one word used by system engineers that covers all the above: robustness. Unfortunately, since it covers all the above it may mean any of the above, all of the above or any combination of the above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, as it concerns using the computerese register/s.

Answer (score 22):

`Robust` is an established technical term that means something specific to engineers and scientists in the [context of systems and control theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_control), so substituting another word for `robust` *when it is used correctly* could cause confusion or create the impression of ignorance. Technical terms cannot really be used "too often". If the word fits, it should be used, since anything else will be less precise. You could throw more words at it and say that a control system "maintains an adequate phase margin irrespective of moderate variations in system parameters", but saying it is "robust" conveys a very similar meaning in fewer words.

You also state that you think the word is often used incorrectly but don't state how- there are terms such as *reliable* or *[high-availability](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/wireless/aironet-1130-ag-series/qa_c67-714540.html)*, *fast-failover* or *[redundant](http://www.controldesign.com/articles/2010/snappac1003/)* that might fit in such cases.

Comment: Exactly.  In this context, 'robust' is arguably a *term of art*.  (I say arguably only because some definitions specify that a term of art has a very specific technical meaning, not just a well-understood one.)

Comment: AT&T (when it was still the giant telephone company) even had a rule for documentation to avoid synonyms. I can't recall if " robust" was in it, but the idea was that every writer used the same word, even if a perfect synonym was available. It produces boring but highly readable documentation.

Answer (score 14):

*Robust* in the context you are describing normally means that the process or system can handle (or bounce back from) problems caused by unexpected events or circumstances.

I think that *robust* is perfectly fine and well-understood if this is the meaning you are looking for.

*Resilient* may be an alternative with similar meaning.

If you are looking for a word with some different meaning you may want to explicitly define which meaning you desire.

Answer (score 8):

The word `robust` has a specific meaning in the context of computer systems. It refers to systems that are not fragile, meaning that they are not easily crashed or put into an error state, or are able to gracefully recover from error states. Since `robust` essentially means `not fragile`, it sounds like the word `antifragile` is a synonym, but `antifragile` has a different, more esoteric meaning. According to http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/anti-fragility.asp "anti-fragility goes beyond robustness; it means that something does not merely withstand a shock *but actually improves because of it*". If you're using "antifragile" to describe a computer system, you're probably using it wrong, because computer systems as a rule cannot be made to function better by being put into an error state or being given bad input.

Comment: Netflix is the exception to the rule. They deliberately crash theirs servers to improve their system as a whole. Partly as a form of continuous error-recovery testing that happens every minute but mostly to force programmers to avoid single-point-of-failures when coding. (google Chaos Monkey)

Comment: You say that *robust* and *fragile* "have a specific meaning". Are they quantifiable metrics?

Comment: @ChrisW Attempts to quantify robustness have been made, but to my knowledge there is no general-case method of quantifying it.

Comment: I can only guess then that it means "reliable" i.e. a long (ideally infinite) time between failures.

Comment: @ChrisW I defined what the word means; if you're suggesting that robustness should be quantified as "time between failures", you're better off taking that thought process to a technical forum.

Comment: You said that it has "a *specific* meaning in the context of computer systems" and I'm not sure that it does. The definition[s] you gave for it included reliable *and* recoverable; and in a comment, you said that several failed attempts have been made to quantify it: which suggests to me that it has a relatively vague meaning or meanings.

Comment: I apologize, you are right: it does have a relatively specific meaning, when compared with the other words "effective, efficacious, and sound" mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel robust is used too often and incorrectly when describing processes and systems.

Some related words (from system or network engineering) include:

- Available (spends most of its time being up).
- Reliable (doesn't go down very often).
- Recoverable (fixable when it does go down)

  - Resilient (self-recovers from failures).
  - Maintainable or Repairable (operator recovers from failures).

---

"Reliable" can be a measure of [MTBF (mean time between failures)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures).

"Recoverable" is a measure of [MTTR (mean time to recover)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_to_recovery).

"Available" is [the fraction of time that it's 'up'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability), calculable as ((MTBF) / (MTBF + MTTR)).

---

Some examples of phrases which mean "highly available" include "[zero downtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability#System_design_for_high_availability)" and (a phrase that was probably never commonly-known except in network engineering) "[carrier grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_grade)".

---

> What would be other possible words to describe processes and systems besides: effective, efficacious, and sound?

These other words (i.e. "effective, efficacious, and sound") don't mean "robust".

Alternatives for some of these other words include "useful", "usable", "widely used", "well designed", "well implemented", and/or "well run".

Not to mention "feature rich", "multi-platform", "mobile", "affordable", etc., but you can't really ask here for a list of all adjectives which can be applied to processes and systems.

Answer (score 0):

For processes I would like sound, strong, or vital.

Comment: Thanks, just discovered this forum and think the concept is great.

Comment: Press the robust up button on my answer.

Comment: And welcome ...

: D

Comment: If you **_really_** like an answer? And it fills the requirements you were after? There is an ACCEPT where you can click it, @Ben Daniels, and a cool little green check appears.

Again, welcome!

Comment: "Vital" could very easily be construed as "essential" rather than "robust."